# Sharing variable to laravel layouts

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I need to share variable to standart layout.app, but when i try to do it-the variable in blade is undefined.
There is the controller part:

```
public function SidebarOffice(){
    $facultys=Faculty::all();
      return view('layouts.app', compact('facultys'));
}
```

And the layout.app part

```
 @foreach($facultys as $faculty)
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">{{$faculty->id}}</a>
                @endforeach
```

I also saw a way with a View::share. Can it work out with him?

Comment: Welcome to SO... use this https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#view-composers

Answer (score 0):

Trying doing it with 'with' method.

It should look something like this:

```
return view('layouts.app')->with(compact('facultys')));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return view('layouts.app',['facultys'=>$facultys]);
```